Get fields of updated row in Mysql2
I want to get the image field of the updated row so i can send it to the client, it works when using SELECT but when using UPDATE it only returns some information about the process like affectedRows, insertId..etc:
    const user = await DB.execute(
      "UPDATE `users` SET `email` = ?",[email]
    );
    
    console.log(user[0].image); 

result of console.log(user); :
[
  ResultSetHeader {
    fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 1,
    insertId: 0,
    info: 'Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0',
    serverStatus: 2,
    warningStatus: 0,
    changedRows: 0
  },
  undefined
]


You certainly need to perform a SELECT query after the UPDATE operation to fetch the updated data.
NB: (MySQL 8.0.21 and above), I have also not tested it but in theory it should work, You need to return the image immediately after update.
Here is a code snippet to guide you.
const [rows] = await DB.execute(
  "UPDATE `users` SET `email` = ? WHERE `id` = ? RETURNING `image`", [email, userId]
);


if (rows.length > 0) {
  const image = rows[0].image;
  console.log(image); // gets the role
}

Alternatively You can try and do this
await DB.execute(
  "UPDATE `users` SET `email` = ? WHERE `id` = ?", [email, userId]
);


// after updating the user column find the image
const [rows] = await DB.execute(
  "SELECT `image` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?", [userId]
);
if (rows.length > 0) {
  const image = rows[0].image;
  console.log(image); 
}


it's a syntax error for me

Hi where does it point to? @AasemShoshari what is the error?
maybe it is the rows.length> 0 I skipped that part apologies

@AasemShoshari. I have updated the code... let's see what happens.

it seems like the only possible solution for now
